# How to highlight filter/search hits in Android Studio Logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

I filter my Logcat lines based on a single String, as depicted below:

[image: I have filtered/searched my logcat for "Aggregate"]

But there I face numerous long long lines and I have much trouble recognizing the wanted values in the middle of the lines. For example, in the above picture, it would be to much convenience to see all "Aggregate" keywords highlighted.

### Is there any way to highlight the filter/search hits on the Logcat console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I see, you use the "Filter", that will show all only lines with word matches to your filter.

If you want to search inside the filter results and get highlighted text matches, click on Cmd+s (on Mac) or Ctrl+s (on PC) and search away (for your example, type "Aggregate")

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, just click on the logcat window and press `Ctrl+f`.