# Android Studio: Logcat search vs. filter

Tags: android, android-studio, logging, logcat

I have a lot of output in my logcat (Android Monitor) which in which I would like to find a specific part. This part starts with a keyword, which is followed by several logs with information I want to check.

I know there is the possibilty to filter the logcat by the Log level and searching for expressions. When I type the keyword in the UI only the logs are filtered by the keyword.

I am interessted in the lines/logs which are followed by the keyword. Is there a search option, where no information is filtered and the results are shown in the complete log?

Commands proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410335/how-to-highlight-filter-search-hits-in-android-studio-logcat) like Ctrl+s do not work.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+f?

Comment: Of course i tried ;)

Comment: Are you using a recent version of the Android SDK? When I open monitor an go to Window->ShowView(), I get the option of _logcat_ and _logcat (deprecated)_. _logcat_ has find, _logcat (deprecated)_ does not. This is in version 24.4.1 of Android Device Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

a while ago I had the same problem and created a Logger helper class which help me by tagging the android logs automatically with the line_number, ClassName and Method name via reflection, this had helped me a lot, for example when I just want to filter the output of a method I write the name of the method in the logcat filter and it just gives me all logs inside that method, same with line numbers and Classes, try it out I have made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/eefret/a9c7ac052854a10a8936) with it.

To use it is easy just do Logger.getLogger and assign to some easy name like log then log like normally just `log.d("string")` without the tag and it automatically takes the line method and class, It has good documentation on it so you might be able to tweak it if you want, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, unfortunately I can not edit the logging because its in a library.